# What's the max size of Set container in Node.js? How many elements it can store?

Tags: node.js, set, containers

What's the max size of `Set` container in JavaScript (Node.js environment)? 
I'm getting an error

```
(node:189755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Set maximum size exceeded 
at Set.add (<anonymous>)
at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/backend/dist/src/executor/executor.worker.js:116:43)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

without specific limit number.

What I have to do? What's the limit of `Set` container? 
Thank you!